# R melted dataframe rank

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

I Have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
> head(female.meth.ordered)
        Var1                                     Var2      value RankMeth
1 cg25296477 ES__WA09_passage39_Female____87.1429.1.1 0.85581970        1
2 cg01003813 ES__WA09_passage39_Female____87.1429.1.1 0.91677790        1
3 cg13176022 ES__WA09_passage39_Female____87.1429.1.1 0.04714496        1
4 cg26484667 ES__WA09_passage39_Female____87.1429.1.1 0.85785770        1
5 cg21028156 ES__WA09_passage39_Female____87.1429.1.1 0.04065772        1
6 cg11503671 ES__WA09_passage39_Female____87.1429.1.1 0.82933710        1
```

There are 606528 rows to this data frame.
Row Var2 contains 54 unique sample names.

```
> unique(female.meth.ordered$Var2)

[1] ES__WA09_passage39_Female____87.1429.1.1                   
 [2] ES__WA09_passage39_Female____87.1429.2.1                   
 [3] ES__MEL4_passage35_Female____127.378.3.1                   
 [4] ES__CSC14_passage29_Female____197.1296.1.2                 
 [5] ES__CM6_passage19_Female____244.622.1.1                    
 [6] ES__HES2_passage105_Female____32.135.4.1  
54 Levels: ES.parthenote__LLC15_passage45_Female____317.905.1.1 ...
```

I want to assign the "RankMeth" column a rank of 1 for the first 10 unique hits in "Var2" column. Then assign "RankMeth" column a rank of 2 for the next 10 unique hits in the "Var2" column. And so on for ranks 3,4,5.

Comment: Does `require(dplyr); female.meth.ordered %>% mutate(RankMeth= as.integer(factor(Var2)))` do what you want?

Comment: This is certainly close. However, I want to only have 5 different ranks. This ranks 1-54. The unique hits in the Var2 is already ordered in least to greatest, so I really just need to select them in groups of 10 and assign a rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution could be as:

Approach:

Take the unique `Var2`and rank by dividing `row_number` with `10`. This will provide `Var2` with rank in group of `1-10`. Say its the `meth_rank`.

Join `meth_rank` with 'female.meth.ordered`to find out corresponding`MethRank` for rows.

```
meth_rank <- unique(female.meth.ordered$Var2) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
     mutate(RankMeth = ceiling(row_number()/10))

colnames(meth_rank) <- c("Var2", "RankMeth")
#Join meth_rank with female.meth.ordered to populate rank.
female.meth.ordered %>% 
  select(-RankMeth) %>%
  inner_join(meth_rank, by="Var2") 
#Result will be generated with headings as
# Var1        Var2      value RankMeth
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Again, this is close, but in the end my rank meth column appears to have ranks up to 27.

Comment: I have modified my solution to divide by 10. If you take latest then rank will be only upto 6.

Comment: Wait, I saw that you edited the second row with /10. It works perfectly. Thank you!